# Service Reference namespace becomes unknown after I 'Update' the service reference

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, wcf, service-reference

Service Reference namespace becomes unknown after I 'Update' the service reference.
Has any one else encountered/resolved this issue?
The changes I make to the Service Reference code are sometimes so minor, and always in method, never to the contract or anything and after update the service reference, VS2008 no longer recognizes the namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got so frustrated with this issue that I finally just got away from using the automatic Update Service Reference feature in VS2008.  It always seemed to me to nest the generated client code in an additional namespace that I didn't want.

If you have access to both the client and server sides, I would suggest watching this [video](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=122) at dnrTV.com that explains how simple it is to bypass the VS2008 update.